# Regex to fetch Values Present after Equals to and present within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ6qZ.png)

Need to fetch Values Present to the right side of equals to and present in between double quotes.

Comment: Why isn't your current approach working? Please share your current attempt in your question. Also it's better to include the actual code or xml data in your question and not as an image. Press [edit] to adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: There are tons of xml libraries that can do this job even better than a regex can. Consider trying some of those.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a sample of the data you want to parse? If what you want to do is for statements like:

```
var var1 = 1234;
var var2 = 34;
var var3 =1233;
```

You can use the following as pattern and replacement: `=(?<rightSide>\s*(?<value>\d+))` and `="$2"`